# Should I Put Useful Java Libraries on my Resume?

Tags: software-industry, resume, software-development, software

I'm currently 2 months into my first full time software engineering job, and getting a lot of experience with technology they don't teach you in college, like Project Lombok, Mockito, Google Guice Injections, etc.

My question is, should I put these technologies on my resume? Or is it assumed that Java developers are expected to know such things/variants of them? If I do put them on my resume, what's a good way to categorize such libraries/skills?

Comment: You mean include them under the skills you have? You're just using these, right?

Comment: Under "other skills" I have those along with Numpy, bootstrap, Scikit-learn, apache spark, hadoop... for about 3 lines. Basically tools I ever had to use to get something done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally speaking, I list projects on my resume.  In the description of those projects I'll list the top level tech used.

To be honest, I'm not sure that Project Lombok applies as it looks like it is more of an editor extension.  Mockito and Google Juice do seem like they'd be items I'd list with the projects I used them on.

For example:

> **2015-06 to 2016-02**
>    *project: Dental Appointment Manager*
>    Part of a 5 person team responsible for business object layer development utilizing Java and Google Juice.  Used Mockito to generate all unit tests.

I used to have a skills section but, tbh, as a hiring manager I never found those useful as people tended to fill in whatever buzzwords they could.  Even if they only just read about it.

Comment: Yeah I felt that way typing in every bit of interesting technology I've used. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Fully agree you should put this experience on your resume but I would also recommend grouping them together under a "technology experience" section preferably towards the top. You do yourself a diservice by hiding technological experience within the body of your resume.

Comment: @Dank:  Personally, I would put Java under technology experience but not the frameworks.  Frameworks come and go; often at the same speed that full projects do.

Answer (score 3):

Just a *slightly* different answer from NotMe - I generally had a "skills" section in my resume, where I just *dumped* all the tools I used. It was really useful because recruiters typically have software that scans cvs for whatever they need - and often they look for silly things, if only because they're not clear what they're hiring for.

To that end, I'd recommend that if you can use a tool/language/thing, you always put it in your skills section.

For when your CV is read by a human, you want  to have as NotMe has put - a job, the role, and the technology used. That then makes clear when you last used the technology, and ties it to whatever you used it for.

But in short, there is no earthly reason to leave off a skill. Feel free to stick in "IntelliJ" or what have you there - there's no reason to bog down your job description with each individual skill either, you just use the "skills" section to bypass the automatic filtering.

Comment: This is also an interesting perspective. Thanks @bharai!

Answer (score 2):

Considering that the first layer of a company that want to recruit you is not always a tech people or won't take the time to check what are all the unkown libraries you mention I would suggest to put some general category like :

> - Testing library : Mockito, JUnit
> - Database : SQL : PostgreSQL, NoSQL : Cassandra, ...
> - General framework : Spring, Google Juice Injection

This is usefull because it present the general category of things where you have some expertise even if you aren't familiar with the one library that use the company.

Also you will often notice that in most of job offer, there is a list of technologies required/wished, if you master some of them, you want to put them on your resume and eventually detail on your level of mastery of them ("beginner", "intermediary", or if you don't like those words, put the time you practiced them).

On a sidenote : I don't think that a simple tool like Lombok is worth the mention is you lack a bit of place in your Resume.